# How to put executable to /usr/bin?

Tags: command-line, eclipse, paths

I downloaded eclipse and extracted it to `/opt`.

My question is how can I make it run from terminal as like other programs like javac, java. I did with `update-alternatives` as follows:

```
sudo update-alternatives --install "/usr/bin/eclipse" "eclipse" "/opt/eclipse/eclipse" 1
```

I didn't get any error. I traversed and saw `/usr/bin/eclipse` was there, So I did:

```
sudo eclipse
```

and I got:

```
sudo: eclipse: command not found
```

1. Is this possible to execute command `eclipse` and my eclipse would start?
2. How can I make my User Program as one of the executable programs from
   terminal?
3. Am I using `update-alternatives` for correct purpose?
4. Any other solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just run `eclipse` and it will start. There is no need to run it with `sudo`. The `update-alternatives --install` made soft link needed to launch Eclipse. That's the purpose of this tool.

However, if you install Eclipse from Software Center, it may override this link, so it is better to place it in `/usr/local/bin`. This directory has priority when executing commands by default.

Other solution is to manually `sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin`. Notice that I'm using `/usr/local` prefix because it's more appropriate in this case.

UPD: It seems something wrong went while you was unpacking Eclipse. The execution bit has gone. To restore it, you need to run:

```
sudo chmod +x /opt/eclipse/eclipse
```

Comment: I did sudo ln -s /opt/eclipse/eclipse /usr/local/bin it was fine. Later I did sudo eclipse still same error & I know in this case it isn't neccessary to place it in /usr/bin or /usr/bin/local but wanted to learn. :)

Comment: @DpN just don't use `sudo`. There is no reason for it and that is what is causing the problem.

Comment: On using only eclipse command its replying this bash: /usr/local/bin/eclipse: Permission denied

Comment: @DpN Use `sudo chmod +x /opt/eclipse/eclipse` then run `eclipse`.

Comment: /opt/eclipse/plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.gtk.linux.x86_64_1.1.200.v20140116-2212/eclipse_1508.so: cannot open shared object file: Permission denied

Comment: Got this error after doing your last comment

Comment: @DpN Can you reinstall Eclipse into `/opt/eclipse`? It seems you done something wrong.

Comment: @Danatela SOLVED user didnt had permission. I solved it. with this...sudo chmod -R deepen:deepen /opt/eclipse then sudo chmod -R u+rw+x /opt/eclipse & it worked & also learned! :) thank you!

Answer (score 1):

For those looking **to put an executable to /usr/bin**, as the tittle.

```
sudo cp ./TheProgram /usr/bin
```

So you can now launch **TheProgram** from anywhere by just typing:

```
TheProgram
```

This is okay if your executable can run **static with no dependencies**.

We can use [Shebang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_(Unix)) scripts the same way, this does not have to be a binary.